# Unable to kill norton security on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, norton-security

I'm trying to end norton security using task manager but i keep getting access denied.

I've tried to change the start up type in services but the start up option is grayed out and permanently set to automatic.

Tried booting up in safe mode and the start up is still grayed out and set to automatic.

Anyone know how I can end this task or change the start up type. The license has expired so it's not really doing much besides using up unnecessary memory.

Answer (score 1):

You don't kill it - you uninstall it, as follows:

1. From the Start menu, click the Control Panel
2. Select Programs, Program and Features
3. Find in the list the Norton Security product
4. Right-click it and select Uninstall or Remove
5. If the User Account Control window appears, click Yes.
6. Follow the on-screen instructions to select your uninstall preference
7. Norton uninstaller will run and complete
8. Restart the computer.

Comment: You may need to run the Norton removal tool to finish cleanup: https://www.nortonsecurityonline.com/security-center/norton-removal-tool.html

Comment: Run the cleanup tool only after restarting the computer and only if you really need to.